# Follow path breaks up parent-child positions

Tags: animation, constraints

I have a starship that I would like to go along a nurbs path. The starship is constituted by several objects (hull, lights, etc.) where the hull is set as the parent for the remaining parts so that I can move the ship easily.

When I select the ship, the nurbs path, click `Ctrl+P` and select Follow Path, the lights jump to the other corner of the scene, and so do other parts of the ship. What could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I can assist without seeing the actual file, but sometimes it helps to parent the main mesh, in your case the hull of the ship, to an empty, and set that empty to follow the path.

Comment: Thank you, it worked :-) It could have occurred to me though :-D